# Packets not being read TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

im having a problem with sockets i was losing packets on the client side, i have a certain method in the server that could potencially send 3 packets really fast to a lot of clientes. After debugging it i found the problem wasnt the server itself but the client, he is not being able to read, my bet is it is not calling the WaitForData fast enough, so he really never knows he is recieving a packet.  I currently have a solution but it is not the best one since im crippling the server by using an await Task.Delay. Any ideas of how to improve the timing of the method RecibirPaquetes (this actually process the packets and fires up an event for the front app)? or any other ideas of how to handle this particular problem? I leave the 2 methods in question here

```
    public void WaitForData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (wdCallBack == null)
            {
                wdCallBack = new AsyncCallback(RecibirPaquetes);
            }
            SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
            theSocPkt.thisSocket = _cliente;
            m_result = _cliente.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer,
                                                    0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                                    SocketFlags.None,
                                                    wdCallBack,
                                                    theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            //this basically resets the client if the waitfordata fails
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mataPrograma.bat");
        }
    }


 private void RecibirPaquetes(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketPacket server = (SocketPacket)ar.AsyncState;

            int cant_recibido;
            try
            {
                cant_recibido = server.thisSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                Log("cant_recibido OK", LogSeverity.NORMAL);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log($"cant_recibido Fallo: {ex.Message}", LogSeverity.ERROR);
                server.thisSocket.Close();

                server.thisSocket = null;

                if (ConexionCerrada != null)
                {
                    ConexionCerrada();
                }

                return;
            }

            if (cant_recibido == 0)
            {
                Log($"cantidad recibida es nula se cierra conexion", LogSeverity.NORMAL);

                server.thisSocket.Close();

                server.thisSocket = null;

                if (ConexionCerrada != null)
                {
                    ConexionCerrada();
                }

                return;
            }

            server.thisSocket.NoDelay = true;

            byte[] paqueteRecibido = new byte[cant_recibido];

            Array.Copy(server.dataBuffer, paqueteRecibido, cant_recibido);

            var paquete = paqueteRecibido.Deserializar();

            if (MensajeRecibido != null)
            {
                MensajeRecibido(paquete as PaqueteServidor);
                Log($"RecibirPaquete: Comando = {((PaqueteServidor)paquete).Comando.ToString()} Contenido = {paquete.Datos}", LogSeverity.NORMAL);
            }
            else
            {
                Log($"FALLO! RecibirPaquete: Comando = {((PaqueteServidor)paquete).Comando.ToString()} Contenido = {paquete.Datos}", LogSeverity.ERROR);
            }
            if (PaqueteComando(paquete as PaqueteServidor) != Comando_Servidor.EXPULSAR && (PaqueteComando(paquete as PaqueteServidor) != Comando_Servidor.CAMBIAR_SESION || soyMonitor))
            {
                WaitForData();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log($"RecibirPaquete: {ex.Message}", LogSeverity.ERROR);
            if (MensajeError != null)
            {
                MensajeError(ex);
            }
            WaitForData();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: adding how the server sends the packets

```
 public void EnviarPaquete(PaqueteServidor paquete, Socket cliente, ENVIAR_A tipo, List<ClienteConectado> custom = null)
    {
        try
        {
            semaphorePaquetes.Wait();

            var conectados = this.clientesConectados.ToList(); //probar esto

            paqueteId += 1;
            paquete.Serial = paqueteId;

            switch (tipo)
            {

                case ENVIAR_A.TODOS:

                    foreach (var item in conectados)
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.TODOS_MENOS_TARGET:

                    foreach (var item in conectados.Where(w => w._socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() != cliente.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.SOLO_LEGISLADORES:

                    foreach (var item in conectados.Where(w => w.Actor.Labor.id_cargo_tipo == 0))
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.ESTRADO:

                    foreach (var item in conectados.Where(w => w.Estrado == true))
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.NO_ESTRADO:

                    foreach (var item in conectados.Where(w => w.Estrado == false))
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.TARGET:


                    if (cliente.Connected)
                    {
                        cliente.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                        this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                        this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                    }

                    break;

                case ENVIAR_A.CUSTOM:

                    foreach (var item in custom)
                    {
                        if (item._socket.Connected)
                        {
                            item._socket.Send(paquete.Serializar(), 0, paquete.Serializar().Length, SocketFlags.None);

                            this.cantPaquetesEnviados += 1;
                            this.bytesEnviados += Convert.ToUInt64(paquete.Serializar().Length);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            aLogear.Enqueue(new Log("EnviarPaquete: " + ex.Message, TipoLog.ERROR, ClaseLog.SERVER));
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphorePaquetes.Release();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Considering that TCP is reliable protocol, it can't loose packets without errors. The problem could be in the peer sending the packets, or in the program receiving them.  A common problem is that sometimes people forget that TCP is a *streaming* protocol, without packets or message boundaries. You might need to receive multiple times to get a single "message", or might get more than a single message when reading.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well it somehow doesnt throw any problems the server since the packet is being send but the client is not waiting for anything to recieve.

Comment: Then it almost certainly received the data as a result of a *previous* call to `Receive`. I.e. the server may have sent `D1`, `D2` and `D3` with three separate `Send`s, but you may have received in one call `D1D2D3` and only *processed* `D1`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that cannot happen since back in the early days of development happened something of the sort, and the program used to crash. I have a log that tells me exactly what the packet came with and the D3 packet is missing D1,D2 come separately

Comment: That's your assertion, but we can't see any code that clearly handles that, and the odds for something along those lines happening are *far* higher than "despite TCP being described as a reliable transport, it sometimes fails to deliver data and nobody has noticed this before". Please give us a [mcve] to work from.